# MacOS - determine the Network Account Server with code

Tags: objective-c, macos, network-programming

I want to detect at runtime of my Mac application (written in Objective-C) if the user's Mac is joined to an Active Directory Server or Open Directory Server and/or any sort of "network account server".  And to read the string of that setting if it exists.  That is, the the setting from the Login Options pane of the "Users & Groups" applet in Systems Preference.  See picture below.

Specifically, just reading the string of the specified server would be sufficient.

What's API set should I be looking at to read this setting?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A computer can be bound to multiple network account servers at one time. To list them you could use the OpenDirectory framework by creating an ODSession and list all registered nodes.

```
#import <OpenDirectory/OpenDirectory.h>

...

ODSession *mySession = [ODSession defaultSession];
NSError *err;
NSArray *nodeNames = [mySession nodeNamesAndReturnError:&err];
NSLog(@"nodeNames=%@", nodeNames);
```

I'm bound to Mac-mini.local OpenDirectory Server, and that outputs this:

```
nodeNames=(
    "/Contacts",
    "/LDAPv3/Mac-mini.local",
    "/Local/Default",
    "/Search"
)
```

[image]

To get further information about a registered node, just create an **ODNode** instance from the node name in the nodeNames array and use that to query that node.

```
ODNode *node = [[ODNode alloc] initWithSession:mySession name:@"/LDAPv3/Mac-mini.local" error:&err];
```

Or, you could also create an **ODNode** instance of a top node, like the /LDAPv3 node, directly and just ask for it's subnodes, like this:

```
ODNode *node = [[ODNode alloc] initWithSession:mySession name:@"/LDAPv3" error:&error];
NSArray *subnodes = [node subnodeNamesAndReturnError:&err];
NSLog(@"subnodes=%@", subnodes);
```

That gave me this output:

```
subnodes=(
    "/LDAPv3/Mac-mini.local"
)
```

**Note:** there is also [-unreachableSubnodeNamesAndReturnError:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MacOSXServer/Reference/ODNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ODNode/unreachableSubnodeNamesAndReturnError:)

If you need more info about this framework, the documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000917-CH1-SW1)